# having problem with giving deployment using kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, devops, kompose

i had this docker compose file which is working absolutely fine.But the i use "kompose convert -f docker-compose.yam -o deploy.yaml" in order to get yaml file for kubernetes deployment.

but when i go for "kubectl apply -f deploy.yaml"

i am getting this error 
"service/cms created
service/mysqldb created
persistentvolumeclaim/my-datavolume configured
unable to recognize no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
unable to recognize no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "extensions/v1beta1"

i am using minikube. 
Please help me out.

docker-compose file content

```
version: "2"
services:
  cms:
    image: 1511981217/cms_mysql:0.0.2
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - cms-network
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb

  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:8
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - cms-network
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=cmsdb  
    volumes:
      - my-datavolume:/var/lib/mysql

networks:
  cms-network: 

volumes:
  my-datavolume:
```

deploy.yaml file content

````
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    annotations:
      kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml -o kubemanifests_2.yaml
      kompose.version: 1.19.0 (f63a961c)
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      io.kompose.service: cms
    name: cms
  spec:
    ports:
    - name: "8080"
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
    selector:
      io.kompose.service: cms
  status:
    loadBalancer: {}
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    annotations:
      kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml -o kubemanifests_2.yaml
      kompose.version: 1.19.0 (f63a961c)
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      io.kompose.service: mysqldb
    name: mysqldb
  spec:
    ports:
    - name: "3306"
      port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
    selector:
      io.kompose.service: mysqldb
  status:
    loadBalancer: {}
- apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    annotations:
      kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml -o kubemanifests_2.yaml
      kompose.version: 1.19.0 (f63a961c)
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      io.kompose.service: cms
    name: cms
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    strategy: {}
    template:
      metadata:
        annotations:
          kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml -o kubemanifests_2.yaml
          kompose.version: 1.19.0 (f63a961c)
        creationTimestamp: null
        labels:
          io.kompose.service: cms
      spec:
        containers:
        - image: 1511981217/cms_mysql:0.0.2
          name: cms
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
          resources: {}
        restartPolicy: Always
  status: {}
- apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    annotations:
      kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml -o kubemanifests_2.yaml
      kompose.version: 1.19.0 (f63a961c)
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      io.kompose.service: mysqldb
    name: mysqldb
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    strategy:
      type: Recreate
    template:
      metadata:
        annotations:
          kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml -o kubemanifests_2.yaml
          kompose.version: 1.19.0 (f63a961c)
        creationTimestamp: null
        labels:
          io.kompose.service: mysqldb
      spec:
        containers:
        - env:
          - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
            value: cmsdb
          - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
            value: root
          image: mysql:8
          name: mysqldb
          ports:
          - containerPort: 3306
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
            name: my-datavolume
        restartPolicy: Always
        volumes:
        - name: my-datavolume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: my-datavolume
  status: {}
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: null
    labels:
      io.kompose.service: my-datavolume
    name: my-datavolume
  spec:
    accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 100Mi
  status: {}
kind: List
metadata: {}
```
````

Answer (score 0):

`extensions/v1beta1` was deprecated in kubernetes version `1.16` .Change `extensions/v1beta1` to `apps/v1` in the yaml and it should work with a kubernetes cluster which is of version higher than `1.16`

Comment: Well the error you have in the question is solved now by the answer...since this question is closed you should accept this answer and ask a different question with the new  error